# Too many fields defined

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, join

I've a weird issue with MS access 2007.
If I run the following query:

```
SELECT QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.*, QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.*
FROM QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS
INNER JOIN QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND
ON QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat = QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat
```

It works, no troubles, then I want to include missing records with left/right join so I run:

```
SELECT QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.*, QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.*
FROM QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS
INNER JOIN QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND
ON QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat = QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat
UNION ALL
SELECT QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.*, QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.*
FROM QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS
LEFT JOIN QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND
ON QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat = QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat
WHERE QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.*, QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.*
FROM QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS
RIGHT JOIN QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND
ON QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat = QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat
WHERE QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat IS NULL
```

And I get: too many fields defined

I don't understand... I'm selecting the exact amount of fields, where is this error coming from guys?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: try using an explicit column list...

Comment: Hi Mitch, the thing is that I've a very very long list lol
In fact, if I try with only one or two fields it works, but not if I include everything

Comment: with no disrespect to either MS or yourself, Access is not a full-featured database product.  It is intended for simple uses by non-technical users and does this well - but too often such products get used for things they're not designed for.  If you're trying to do simulate a full join (as described below) you are clearly technically sophisticated, and you deserve to use a better database product.  I strongly suggest that you try another database that can do this job better and easier.

Comment: Hi Bob, no offense at all, what you're saying is right and straight forward. The only thing you don't know is that MS access is a business requirement in my project, so I can't use another database, I've to stick to it and well... to make it work somehow :). Thank you for your highlight though ;)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: while Access can indeed be used by novice users, it's also a powerful development platform that developers who aren't novices can do a lot with. Jet/ACE is the database engine, and it does have its limitations (and its own SQL dialect), but those are not really relevant here. The data schema is a bad design, seems to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem has nothing to do with your **JOINS**, but with your **UNIONS**!

I Googled your error message and found this: http://www.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0002.htm. Given that you have so many fields... Maybe that's the problem? Note that the various articles talk about MS Access's **INTERNAL** field count. Maybe the various UNION ALL clauses are limited by that internal field count

Comment: I tried compacting the table... but it didn't fix anything over there

Comment: What does "compacting" mean? And how many fields do you get, when you select * from both tables?

Comment: I have 199 fields. And compacting is a tool in database that resets fields counters (because if you drop a column for example it doesn't get decreased, so the compact is a way of cleaning rabbish out of the database)

Comment: As a test case, could you just explicitly select 1-2 fields from each table and use them in the UNIONs to see if that would work? Otherwise, I agree, that I might be on the wrong track... :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like other people have similar problems with less than 255 fields... http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1678084.php. Looks like a really nasty issue.

Comment: Anyone needing 200 fields has a schema error. Certainly we all sometimes have to deal with some pile of crap that some idiot created and we have to live with, but the problem here is simply bad design. There may or may not be workarounds -- it's hard to say since the actual requirements are not outlined.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton SAP (Navision probably also) has tables with more than 255 columns. Now I cannot export the data to access and work on it just because some stupidly low limitations. Assuming those two are rather popular financial software I would use word "often" instead of "sometimes".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I don't think you would get any results from a left-join query that requires the left join column to be null, and the same for a right-join query where the right join column is null, which seems to be what's going on here. Maybe try switching the left and right joins?

Comment: When I execute the left/right joins separately I get the expected result actually

Comment: Indeed ! Just got the confirmation... The UNION sees my select as 2 * 200... so 400 columns... This is really dumbass... Thank you guys I'm gonna try to find out another way of solving this...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). It explains pretty well all the different joins.

In your case why don't you use a full outer join ?

```
SELECT QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.*, QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.*
FROM QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS
FULL OUTER JOIN QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND
ON QUERY_LNK_ORDERS_ITEMS.concat = QUERY_LNK_ERASALES_ERACOND.concat
```

Comment: MS Access has no OUTER JOIN unfortunately, and the way I'm doing things in my query is the how to simulate the full outer join actually :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've found that the problem is with the UNIONs (comment on Spiny Norman's answer), I think your only optionis going to be a temporary table (though you might want to define its structure premanently, then insure that valid uses always clear it before repopulating). Then run each of your queries as an insert (maybe with the first as a make-table if you don't go with permanent structure), and select from that for your final result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer to this one other way might lie in separating these and combining in a recordset.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL1)
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL2)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL3)
 .......
```