# Too many fields - Ms Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, export-to-excel

I have a problem, I have table (the sole purpose of this table is to get data and export the data to excel format) which has 200 fields. Not all fields in the table will have data.

I use one union query to get the required data to fill into the table. The three select fill different columns out of the 200 columns (let's say Query1- 2, 3,4, Query2- 22, 33,124, Query3- 24, 53,49). On running the query I get an error message

> Too many fields defined

I tried compact n repair but no help. I also referred [Too many fields defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427984/too-many-fields-defined).

Please suggest as to how can I achieve. The output Excel sheet needs to have all 200 columns in it with data corresponding to all the queries.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128221

The internal column count that Microsoft Access uses to track the number of fields in the table has reached 255, even though you may have fewer than 255 fields in the table. This can happen because Microsoft Access does not change the internal column count when you delete a field. Microsoft Access also creates a new field (increasing the internal column count by 1) for every field whose properties you modify.

Resolution is in the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to 'change the internal column count when you delete a field' - you can copy and paste to create a new table. The new table will un-count the deleted field.